# SwiftUI clear button for all Toggles in a List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and here is what I want to achieve:

I have a `Form` with sections. Each section has a list and each row has a `Toggle` I can select/deselect. Below the list, I have a clear button. With a click, I would like to reset all the `Toggles` to a deselected state.

[image]

Model (each ListSection represents `Section` in `Form`):

```
struct RowItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isSelected: Bool
    var rowName: String
    var amount: Int
}

struct ListSection: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ListSection, rhs: ListSection) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let items: [RowItem]
    let visible: Int
}

class HomeModel: ObservableObject {
    private let items1 = [RowItem(isSelected: false, rowName: "Energy", amount: 24),
                          RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "Automotive", amount: 70),
                          RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "Materials", amount: 56),
                          RowItem(isSelected: false, rowName: "Industrials", amount: 109),
                          RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "Consumer1", amount: 209),
                          RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "Consumer2", amount: 12),]

    private let items2 = [RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "Europe", amount: 302),
                          RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "America", amount: 589),
                          RowItem(isSelected: false, rowName: "Asia", amount: 67),
                          RowItem(isSelected: false, rowName: "Africa", amount: 207),
                          RowItem(isSelected: true, rowName: "Oceania", amount: 9)]

    @Published var sections: [ListSection]

    init() {
        self.sections = [ListSection(title: "Sectors", items: items1, visible: 4),
                         ListSection(title: "Regions", items: items2, visible: 5)]
    }
}

struct ExpandableList: View {
    private var title: String
    private var visibleElements: Int
    private var showAllButtonVisible: Bool
    
    @State private var items: [RowItem]
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    init(title: String, items: [RowItem], visible: Int) {
        self.title = title.lowercased()
        self.items = items
        self.visibleElements = visible
        self.showAllButtonVisible = visible < items.count
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(isExpanded ? 0..<items.count : 0..<Array(items[0..<visibleElements]).count, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack {
                    Text(items[index].rowName).fontWeight(.light)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(items[index].amount)").foregroundColor(.gray).fontWeight(.light)
                    Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                        get: { return items[index].isSelected },
                        set: { items[index].isSelected = $0 }
                    )){}.toggleStyle(.checklist)
                }.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            
            if showAllButtonVisible {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            isExpanded.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        if isExpanded {
                            Label("Show less \(title)", systemImage: "chevron.up").foregroundColor(Color(red: 55/255, green: 126/255, blue: 83/255, opacity: 1)).labelStyle(ImageToRightSideLabelStyle())
                        } else {
                            Label("Show all \(title)", systemImage: "chevron.down").foregroundColor(Color(red: 55/255, green: 126/255, blue: 83/255, opacity: 1)).labelStyle(ImageToRightSideLabelStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyForm: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = HomeModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    ForEach(model.sections, id: \.id) { section in
                        Section {
                            ExpandableList(title: section.title, items: section.items, visible: section.visible)
                        } header: {
                            Text(section.title).font(.title3).foregroundColor(.black).textCase(nil)
                        } footer: {
                            if section != model.sections.last {
                                VStack {
                                    Divider().padding(.top, 15)
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        
                    }
                }.navigationTitle(Text("Filter stocks"))
                
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        for section in model.sections {
                            for var item in section.items {
                                item.isSelected = false
                                print("Tag1 false")
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Clear filters").foregroundColor(.black)
                    }.padding(.leading, 30)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        print("sign up bin tapped")
                    }) {
                        Text("Show 1506 assets")
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .background(Color.green) // If you have this
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 30)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I assume I need to use `Binding` somewhere, but not sure where.

Comment: You need to provide all data related code of view, because it is not clear what is where.

Comment: It is too much to rewrite - you almost everywhere work with copy of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small project to address your issue. The main takeaway is that you need to let `SwiftUI` know when to redraw the view after the model or model element's properties change. That can be done with `@Published` and/or `objectWillChange` which is available to any class conforming to the `ObservableObject` protocol.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    class Model: ObservableObject {
        @Published var items = [
            Item(zone: "America", count: 589),
            Item(zone: "Asia", count: 67),
            Item(zone: "Africa", count: 207),
            Item(zone: "Oceania", count: 9)
        ]
        
        class Item: ObservableObject, Hashable {
            static func == (lhs: ContentView.Model.Item, rhs: ContentView.Model.Item) -> Bool {
                lhs.id == rhs.id
            }
            
            let id = UUID()
            let zone: String
            let count: Int
            
            @Published var selected: Bool = false
            
            init(zone: String, count: Int) {
                self.zone = zone
                self.count = count
            }
            
            func toggle() {
                selected.toggle()
            }
            
            func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
                hasher.combine(id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(model.items.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.zone)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String(item.count))
                    Button {
                        item.toggle()
                        print(index, item.selected)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: item.selected ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                    }
                }
                .padding(10)
                .onReceive(item.$selected) { isOn in
                    model.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                model.items.forEach { item in
                    item.selected = false
                }
                model.objectWillChange.send()
            } label: {
                Text("Clear")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aibo-cora/SwiftUI/blob/main/ResetCheckBoxes.md

Comment: Why is onReceive is necessary although you are using @Published?